# How to programmatically destroy/unmount vue.js 3 components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have a fairly large **vue.js 2** application that has a dynamic tabs mechanism. Users can interact with the application opening and closing tabs, each tab represents a route. To achieve this I'm using vue router and keep alive, like the example bellow.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <keep-alive>
      <router-view :key="routerViewKey"/>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</template>
```

When users click the close tab button, the `$destroy` function is called to remove its component from the cache. I'm migrating this application from vue 2 to vue 3, however, reading the breaking changes [documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/#other-minor-changes) for vue.js 3 we can see this:

> **Removed APIs**
>
> `$destroy` instance method. Users should no longer manually manage the
> lifecycle of individual Vue components.

I didn't find any alternatives so far, so how can I programmatically destroy/unmount a cached component inside keep-alive in **vue.js 3**?

**Edit 1 (Apr/22)**: So far it's still impossible to achieve what `$destroy` did on vue.js 2 in vue.js 3. There is currently a RFC to solve this issue (https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/283), but unfortunately it's opened for more than a year without any feedback.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the unmount command here: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#unmount

Unfortunately, if you want to do it inside your app, the documentation doesn't have any way to do it.
However, after analyzing the object, I found a way to do it. You can achieve it by using this: `this.$.appContext.app.unmount();`

I'm not a huge fan of this solution, given that it can no longer work in a future version, but it works well on my project.

EDIT:
Another way is to extend the `Vue` object according to this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/1802 and https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component

I have slightly improved the function:

```js
function mount(component, { props, children, element, app } = {}) {
    let el = element
  
    let vNode = createVNode(component, props, children)
    vNode.destroy = () => {
        if (el) render(null, el)
        el = null
        vNode = null
    }
    if (app?._context) vNode.appContext = app._context
    if (el) render(vNode, el)
    else if (typeof document !== 'undefined' ) render(vNode, el = document.createElement('div'))
  
    const destroy = () => {
        if (el) render(null, el)
        el = null
        vNode = null
    }
  
    return { vNode, destroy, el }
}
```

You can now track which component you have as children, destroy it from the parent AND the children by using this: `this.$.vnode.destroy();`

However, the new official way seems to use `createApp` now.

Comment: Are you sure `this.$.appContext.app.unmount();` unmounts a current component, not the app? I have tried calling it through `getCurrentInstance().appContext.app.unmount()` in composition API, but it looks like it causes the whole app to unmount, not the current instance of component..

Comment: Back in my project, it worked, maybe I was on a special case. Also, you can use the function described in the EDIT section. It directly adds a destroy function for each vNode which is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `v-if`

```
<template>
  <div
    v-if="!close"
    :class="`z-50 absolute py-4 mx-4 ${position}`"
    data-testid="notification"
  >
      ...
      <div v-if="enableClose" class="cursor-pointer absolute right-1 top-3 text-gray-500 text-2xl" @click="onClose">
        &times;
      </div>
    </Flash>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, render} from "vue";
import Flash from "@/core/shared/components/Layout/Flash.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Toast",
  components: {
    Flash,
  },
  props: {
    ...
    enableClose: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...
  },
  data() {
    return {
      close: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onClose() {
      this.close = true;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```