# How to unmount a Vue3 component in script setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

For example, I have a component like this.

```
<template>
    <el-card @click='destroyCard'>
       ......
    </el-card>
</template>
<script setup>
......
let destroyCard = () => {
    ......
}
onUnmounted(() => {
    console.log('destroyed')
})
</script>
```

I know I can emit a methon to Parent component and destroy the component.But I want to destroy/unmount this component from it self, is it possible?

Comment: of course a hack from the low level API will do it but it will cause a memory leak

Comment: maybe using a `v-if` and your `onUnmounted` is declared in the `ELCard.vue`-file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to destroy/unmount vue.js 3 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163775/how-to-destroy-unmount-vue-js-3-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't vue components can't commit suicide that's true in either angular or react!!

Comment: OK, I think you might be right, because I didn't find any answers in those similar questions, but I don't know why.